# Opencart: How the auto update currency process is working

Tags: php, opencart

I have been analyzing the platforms for shopping cart. I heard about opencart and its auto update currency process. I have surfed to find the process. But I couldn't get solution.

How it is working? Does it use any APIs by default? Is there any possibilities for auto update failure? How can we solve that?

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: See this Maybe helpful for you - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Comment: Do you mean the currency rate or the functionality of changing currency from one to the other

Answer (score 3):

It gets them from http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv

In answer to your question, presumably it would stop working if Yahoo ever discontinued the service or changed the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [colmde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495940/colmde) is right, it is using Yahoo finance web service, but it is still working in my local computer connected to internet.

> How it is working?

As I check the code, there are 3 conditions for currency update to run:

1. When we are entering admin dashboard page (if auto update enabled)
2. When we set Auto Update Currency to Yes in page Setting / Store and we save it (if auto update enabled)
3. When we push button Refresh in page Localisation / Currencies

> Does it use any APIs by default?

Yes, it is using Yahoo finance web service API as [colmde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495940/colmde) mentioned

> Is there any possibilities for auto update failure? How can we solve that?

Of course there is, you can see the code in `/admin/model/localisation/currency.php` in `refresh()` method. You can modify failure handling there. Currently the code will update the value of currency if the content from the web service is not empty.

> Presumably it would stop working if Yahoo ever discontinued the service or changed the URL.

And you're not connected to internet.